# How to write constructors for implicit conversions from instances of a templated class C<Derived> to instances of C<Base>

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, implicit-conversion

I have created a template class derived from `shared_ptr<const T>` that enables a holder of the shared pointer to modify the pointed instance by cloning the instance and reseting the shared_pointer. (`T` can be a clonable class or a class that have a copy constructor whence the weird double definition of the modify method)

`shared_ptr<Base>` can be implicitly constructed/copied by a instance of class `shared_ptr<Derived>`. But my class cannot.

How can I make that possible? I suppose I need to create a templated constructor that accepts argument of type `const_shared_ptr<D>` where `D` is a type derived from the template type `C`. I don't know how to write that. I guess it is possible as `shared_ptr` can do it.

```
template <typename T, typename = int>
struct HasPolymorphicClonage : std::false_type { };
template <typename T>
struct HasPolymorphicClonage <T, decltype(&T::clone, 0)> : std::true_type { };

template<typename C>
class shared_const_ptr : public std::shared_ptr<const C>
{
public :
    shared_const_ptr(const C * c) : std::shared_ptr<const C>(c) {}
    shared_const_ptr() =default;

    // définition de la méthode modify selon que T propose ou non une méthode clone
    template<typename T1 = C>
    typename std::enable_if_t<HasPolymorphicClonage<T1>::value,C&> modify()
    {
        C * remplacant = (*this)->clone();
        this->std::shared_ptr<const C>::reset(remplacant);
        return *remplacant;
    }

    template<typename T1 = C>
    typename std::enable_if_t<!HasPolymorphicClonage<T1>::value,C&> modify()
    {
        C * remplacant = new C(**this); // on utilise le constructeur par recopie
        this->std::shared_ptr<const C>::reset(remplacant);
        return *remplacant;
    }

};
```

Comment: fwiw, its (9) here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a templated constructor accepting a `std::shared_ptr<T>` should work:

```cpp
template<typename C>
class shared_const_ptr : public std::shared_ptr<const C>
{
public :
    // ...

    template <typename T>
    shared_const_ptr(std::shared_ptr<const T> const& other) : std::shared_ptr<const C>(other) {}

};

struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};

int main()
{
    shared_const_ptr<Base> b;
    shared_const_ptr d(new Derived{});
    b = d;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/n45PKE9ff

When constructing `b` from`d`, argument conversion will convert `d` to a `std::shared_ptr<const Derived>`. The constructor is viable because `std::shared_ptr<const Derived>` is convertible to `std::shared_ptr<const Base>`.

Comment: Thank you. You can also take a parameter from the template shared_const_ptr. I was wrongly thinking that template constructor should somewhat control the validity of the template argument. But actually, compilation failure is OK.